# Run MRJob from IPython notebook

Tags: python, mapreduce, jupyter-notebook, mrjob

I'm trying to run mrjob example from IPython notebook

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob


class MRWordFrequencyCount(MRJob):

def mapper(self, _, line):
    yield "chars", len(line)
    yield "words", len(line.split())
    yield "lines", 1

def reducer(self, key, values):
    yield key, sum(values)
```

then run it with code

```
mr_job = MRWordFrequencyCount(args=["testfile.txt"])
with mr_job.make_runner() as runner:
    runner.run()
    for line in runner.stream_output():
        key, value = mr_job.parse_output_line(line)
        print key, value
```

and getting the error:

```
TypeError: <module '__main__' (built-in)> is a built-in class
```

Is there way to run mrjob from IPython notebook?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found the "perfect way" yet, but one thing you can do is create one notebook cell, using the `%%file` magic, writing the cell contents to a file:

```
%%file wordcount.py
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class MRWordFrequencyCount(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        yield "chars", len(line)
        yield "words", len(line.split())
        yield "lines", 1

    def reducer(self, key, values):
        yield key, sum(values)
```

And then have `mrjob` run that file in a later cell:

```
import wordcount
reload(wordcount)

mr_job = wordcount.MRWordFrequencyCount(args=['example.txt'])
with mr_job.make_runner() as runner:
    runner.run()
    for line in runner.stream_output():
        key, value = mr_job.parse_output_line(line)
        print key, value
```

Notice that I called my file `wordcount.py` and that I import the class `MRWordFrequencyCount` from the `wordcount` module -- the filename and module has to match. Also Python caches imported modules and when you change the `wordcount.py`-file iPython will not reload the module but rather used the old, cached one. That's why I put the `reload()` call in there.

Reference: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mrjob/CfdAgcEaC-I/8XfJPXCjTvQJ

**Update (shorter)**
For a shorter second notebook cell you can run the mrjob by invoking the shell from within the notebook

```
! python mrjob.py shakespeare.txt
```

Reference: http://jupyter.cs.brynmawr.edu/hub/dblank/public/Jupyter%20Magics.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is due to [this limitation](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/runners.html#limitations) stated on the MRJob website:

> The file with the job class is sent to Hadoop to be run. Therefore,
>   the job file cannot attempt to start the Hadoop job, or you would be
>   recursively creating Hadoop jobs!The code that runs the job should
>   only run outside of the Hadoop context.

Alternatively, it might be because you didn't have the following ([reference](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/quickstart.html#what-s-happening)):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  
  MRWordCounter.run()  # where MRWordCounter is your job class
```