# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType when running mrjob

Tags: python, mapreduce, google-colaboratory, mrjob

I am new to Google Colab and Python.

I have directed the files from google drive and was trying to run a Map Reduce with the use of mrjob.

```
import sys
sys.argv=['0']

from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.protocol import JSONProtocol, RawValueProtocol
from mrjob.step import MRStep
#creating an mrjob
class averagerating(MRJob):
  def steps(self):
    return [MRStep(mapper=self.mapper_average_rating,reducer=self.reducer_average_rating)]
  #creating a mapping fuction
  def mapper_average_rating(self):
     x_teleplay=dfR_new['teleplay_id']
     y_rating=dfR_new.iloc[:, -1:].mean(axis=1)
     average_rate_per_id=dfR_new.groupby(['teleplay_id'])[['rating']].mean()

     yield y_rating, x_teleplay



  #creating a reducer fuction
  def reducer_average_rating(self,key,values):
     key=average_rate_per_id['teleplay_id']
     values=average_rate_per_id['rating']
     yield key,values
     print(key,values)

 #main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
   averagerating.run()
```

However, it returns type error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-44-d5d6bd5175a1> in <module>()
     27  #main function
     28 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 29    averagerating.run()

7 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py in run(cls)
    614         """
    615         # load options from the command line
--> 616         cls().execute()
    617 
    618     def run_job(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py in execute(self)
    685 
    686         else:
--> 687             self.run_job()
    688 
    689     def make_runner(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py in run_job(self)
    632                             stream=log_stream)
    633 
--> 634         with self.make_runner() as runner:
    635             try:
    636                 runner.run()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py in make_runner(self)
    702 
    703         runner_class = self._runner_class()
--> 704         kwargs = self._runner_kwargs()
    705 
    706         # screen out most false-ish args so that it's readable

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py in _runner_kwargs(self)
    725             # don't screen out irrelevant opts (see #1898)
    726             self._kwargs_from_switches(set(_RUNNER_OPTS)),
--> 727             self._job_kwargs(),
    728         )
    729 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py in _job_kwargs(self)
    244                 self.jobconf(), self.options.jobconf),
    245             libjars=combine_lists(
--> 246                 self.libjars(), self.options.libjars),
    247             partitioner=self.partitioner(),
    248             sort_values=self.sort_values(),

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py in libjars(self)
   1371            ``--libjars`` option
   1372         """
-> 1373         script_dir = os.path.dirname(self.mr_job_script())
   1374 
   1375         paths = []

/usr/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py in dirname(p)
    154 def dirname(p):
    155     """Returns the directory component of a pathname"""
--> 156     p = os.fspath(p)
    157     sep = _get_sep(p)
    158     i = p.rfind(sep) + 1

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

I would like to ask where is the problem in the last line of my code and how could I fix the error?

I added `sys.argv=['0']` is because if I write `sys.argv[]` or not adding `sys.argv` the list index will be out of range.

Comment: is this full error message? It shows first frame and last frame but there are missing `7 frames which may have useful information. Error shows problem with some path which is `None` but It doesn't show where it get this path.

Comment: why do you use `sys.argv=['0']` ? Normally first item on this list should be path to script. I only guess: maybe code uses this path for some reason but you set wrong path and it can't find this path so it gives `None` which gives your error.

Comment: @furas Thanks for the comment! I have updated the error message!

Comment: [Run MRJob from IPython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701101/run-mrjob-from-ipython-notebook)

Answer (score 1):

All problem is because you run it in `Google Colab` which keeps code and all other information as jupyter notebook `.pynb` but it not keep code in `.py`

When `MRJob` runs it then it creates new processes which have to read this code again from file `.py`. Because `juputer notebook` is not `.py` so it can't read it.

As I found in [Run MRJob from IPython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701101/run-mrjob-from-ipython-notebook) you can put code in new cell with `%%file script.py` to save code in file `.py`, and in next cell you can run it as `!python script.py your_data_file.txt`

[image]

This resolve your problem with `expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType` but it still have other problems - it doesn't know `dfR_new` because it runs only code inside `script.py`. You would have to create in `dfR_new` but I think `MRjob` should rather read it from file.

---

Frankly, I don't understand what you try to do in `MRjob` because it make no sense for me. It looks like `mapper` and `reducer` always use the same values so they are useless. `MRjob` read data from text file but it doesn't send it as one string to mapper but it sends it line by line - and this way every line can be modify by separated process - and later `reducer` should get all modificed lines and reduce them to one line. But you works always on the same values from full DataFrame - so MRjob seems useless for this. Simply MRjob is for totally different problems.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!